# How to increase the color space CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, cagradientlayer

I have a Gradient that has three colors, Black, clear, and black. How would you increase the middle section?

The desired effect I am going for is a shading/gradient at the top, clear middle show content can show clearly, and a shading/gradient at the bottom. This is what I have so far.

[image]

How would I increase the middle portion of the gradient? I hope its clear. Here is my code too;

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor],(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor],nil];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Comment: @downvote: why the down vote. I have provided code, and a screen shot. this is shows you what I have tried. Should not have been downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try playing with gradient.locations

```
gradient.locations = @[@(0.2), @(0.8), @(1.0)];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try playing around with the locations.

Answer (score 2):

You should use CAGradientLayer's location property:

An optional array of NSNumber objects defining the location of each gradient stop. Animatable.

The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing. If nil, the stops are spread uniformly across the range. Defaults to nil.

```
gradient.locations = @[@0.3, @0.7, @1.0];
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAGradientLayer/locations)

Answer (score 0):

Try QuartzCode to create gradient using GUI, should have things that you need
www.quartzcodeapp.com

Answer (score 0):

The other answers' code in Swift:

```
gradient.locations = [0.2, 0.8, 1.0]
```